# About sigma algebra (proof of Borel field)

Tags: mathematical-statistics, measure-theory

Suppose that the sample space $S$ of some experiment is finite. Show that the collection of all subsets of $S$ satisfies the three conditions required to be called the collection of events:

1. $S \in \beta $
2. if $A \in \beta, \; A^\complement\in\beta$
3. if $A_{1},A_{2},\ldots,A_{n}\in\beta,\; A_{1}\cup A_{2}\cup\cdots\cup A_{n}\in\beta$

How can I prove the axioms above? That is, how can I show that the collection of all subsets of $S$ satisfies the three conditions required to be called the collection of events?

A detailed explanation of the Borel field and its full proof will help me improve my statistical insight and skills.

Comment: $S$, $A^c$, $A_1 \cup \ldots \cup A_n$ are subsets of $S$, don't you agree ?

Comment: I agree with these. Certainly they are. And then?

Comment: And then you're done: there's nothing left to show.